# Flask-paginate plugin issue: All results show up on same page

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am using Flask-paginate for pagination in my app. The results are fetched from database. The problem is that all results show up on 1st page and when I click on the next page number again all results are displayed on that page. The page number in url changes to 2/3/4 etc. I [this](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-paginate/) as reference. Here is my code snippet

```
from flask.ext.paginate import Pagination
@app.route('/users')
def users_page():

    page_size = 25
    limit = 100

    search = False
    q = request.args.get('q')
    if q:
        search = True
    try:
        page = int(request.args.get('page', 1))
    except ValueError:
        page = 1
    with session_scope() as session:
        users = users_dao.get_users(session, limit=limit)
        pagination = Pagination(page=page, total=len(users), per_page=page_size, search=search, record_name='users')
        return render_template("users.html", users=users, pagination=pagination)
```

The pagination info on html page says `displaying 1-25 results of 100`. When clicked on page 2, it says `displaying 25-50 results of 100`. So somehow the pagination has figured out on the basis of total and per_page how many results should be displayed but somewhere it fails to force that on number of rows to show. Any idea how to not to show all rows on every page?

PS: I want to use flask-paginate and not flask-sqlalchemy.

The template looks like

```
{{ pagination.info }}
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>User Name</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Country</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for user in users %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ user.user_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.phone_number }}</td>
            <td>{{user.city}}</td>
            <td>{{user.country}}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
{{ pagination.links }}
```

Another thing that I want to add is that limit and page_size in my case are two different things. Limit is the max number of results I want to fetch from the database. Page_size is the number of results I want to show on each page.

Comment: What does your template code look like?

Comment: @nichochar : I just updated my question with the template